# MySQL service hung in "Starting" mode

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install multiple instances of MySQL on a Windows Server 2003 using this [link](http://ardeearam.com/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-mysql-on-a-windows-server/).

First instance which is on port 6699 get configured and working successfully. But when I try to install another instance on default port (3306) MySQL service gets hung on "Starting" status. This is the log

```
140210 17:13:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140210 17:13:20 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140210 17:13:20 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140210 17:13:20 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140210 17:13:20 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140210 17:13:20 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
140210 17:13:21  InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
140210 17:13:21  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
140210 17:13:23  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
140210 17:13:26  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140210 17:13:27 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 0
140210 17:13:27 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 6699
140210 17:13:27 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
140210 17:13:27 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
140210 17:13:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140210 17:13:27 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.25'  socket: ''  port: 6699  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
140210 17:42:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140210 17:42:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140210 17:42:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140210 17:42:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140210 17:42:19 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140210 17:42:19 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140210 17:42:19 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
```

Observe line `140210 17:42:19  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!`

Comment: Could it be that both your instances try to use the same location for the `ibdata` etc files? I doubt that that'll work!

Comment: Ensure all the paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

> InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match

Double check your configuration!

Make a binay backup or entire /var/lib/mysql.

If you don't need most recent data, delete the log files and try to start.

If you need your data, try the followling:

Try innodb_force_recovery = 1 to 6 all six options in an increasing order.

Assume the worst -- innodb disk image corrupted.

If you are lucky you can salvage most of your data, perhaps mysql starts in one of recovery modes, run checksum on each table, see what tables are still ok.

If mysql refuses to start up to certain recovery mode N and crashes on startup with recovery mode N, then go looking for those daily/weekly backups I hope you system was configured to take.